# Finding all unique values including NAs in a dataframe column in R

Tags: r

Importing a .csv file into R using `read.csv` (with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`)

One field is numeric (integers between 0 and 10) but has quite a lot of blanks in it.

`read.csv` gives me a data frame with this field as an `int` column, but with blanks tagged as `NA`. That's ok. But...I wanted a quick line of code to show me the unique values appearing in this field (including `NA`) so I used:

```
levels(as.factor(dataframe$fieldname))
```

but it doesn't include the `NA` entries in there, just the 1-10.

Is there another way to do this, so that I don't miss the `NA` entries?

Comment: `levels(factor(x, exclude = c()))` or with frequencies: 
`table(x, exclude = c())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
unique(dataframe$fieldname)
```